# Spyder Python "object arrays are currently not supported"

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I have a problem in Anaconda Spyder (Python).

Object type array can not be seen under Windows 10 in the **variable explorer**. If I click on *X or Y*, I see an error:

> object arrays are currently not supported.

I have Win 10 Home 64bit (i7-4710HQ) and Python 3.5.2 | Anaconda 4.2.0 (64-bit) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: this is not a problem with anaconda or windows.. the spyder editor simply does not support all datatypes in the variable explorer. under the hood pandas uses numpy arrays which are supported by spyder only if the datatype is a numeric type. it doesn't mean you can't use them, only you can't view them with the variable explorer

Comment: What's unclear about that error message?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. During the python course on udemy.com  - Machine Learning A-Z ™ I noticed that other people (under MAC's) in Spyder can do it. The instructor thinks it should relate with  Win 10. I'm confused:(

Comment: I have the same problem and I am on windows 7 (I am taking the same course on udemy).. I think it has to do with the current version of spyder

Comment: I have the same problem. And I am sure that it worked until the last week. The only change that I made is to allow the software to send anonymous usage data, but I think that is not related.

Comment: Sorry I was wrong. I was clicking on a dataset variable.

Comment: I did mean a Dataframe variable.

Comment: For the udemy course followers, the tutor actually has support for it without manipulating the variables with additional computation. Try this: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49347986/4010017

Answer (score 25, accepted):

(*Spyder developer here*) Support for object arrays will be added in Spyder **4**, to be released in 2019.

Comment: But for the udemy course followers, the tutor actually has support for it. Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/49347986/4010017

Comment: do we have a roadmap? we are in 2019 now

Comment: Spyder 4 will be released (most probably) in September 2019.

Comment: Confirmed : With spyder4 you have can see object array

Comment: @madhairsilence, how did you install Spyder4? I can not install it from Anaconda 3.

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin conda install spyder=4.0.1

Comment: It's really `conda update anaconda`, followed by `conda install spyder=4.0.1`

Answer (score 26):

A good example is here

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
dataset = pd.read_csv('Salary_Data.csv') #in your case right name of your file
X=dataset.iloc[:,:-1].values   #this will convert dataframe to object
df = pd.DataFrame(X)
```

You can view data in dataframe this converts arrray to dataframe .

And the variable explorer accepts the dataframe. The above is correct and checked code

Comment: from which version this functionality has been added? It doesn't work on spyder 3.3 (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS)

Comment: Hi @ashishmalgawa this is not a functionality addition. answer doesn't relate to os you use. The above is just a method to see it in dataframe .i.e incase you want to see in variable explorer .And code works fine for me

Comment: But for the udemy course followers, the tutor actually has support for it without manipulating the variables with additional computation. Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/49347986/4010017

Answer (score 16):

I used the same without `dataFrame` and `.values`.
It worked for me.

```
x = dataset.iloc[:, :-1]
y = dataset.iloc[:,3]
```

Comment: Helpful in my case

Answer (score 10):

> Solution: Downgrade the version of spyder to 3.2.0

You can do this by going to anaconda-navigator.

If you are following the Udemy Course on Machine Learning, probably the instructor is using an older version of spyder and it is working for him. In the newer versions like 3.2.8, it is not working but can be incorporated in the coming versions in the future.

Edit: This answer is not applicable now, since from the others answers we can see that this functionality has been added in >= 4 version of spyder.

Comment: the exact solution for 3.2.8 version of Spider if you're following Udemy Course

Answer (score 6):

I have analyzed the code until the [point](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/blob/10b37bb224124b20ba6fbff85d242cdb68895824/spyder/widgets/variableexplorer/arrayeditor.py#L624) that could be failing for you.

It seems that array editor of Spyder doesn't support showing arrays of mixed types (object arrays).

Here you can see the [supported formats](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/blob/10b37bb224124b20ba6fbff85d242cdb68895824/spyder/widgets/variableexplorer/arrayeditor.py#L44).

Something was confusing for me the first time that I used it: you receive the same editor when you click on a Dataset that when you click on an array variable.

In the case of a variable of type **array**, you receive an **ArrayEditor** widget. I think that call is made [here](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/blob/f1c39fa611cb2b691e86c7818e4ee388a2eaa42b/spyder/widgets/variableexplorer/objecteditor.py#L73).

But in the case of a variable of type **DataFrame**, you receive a **DataFrameEditor**. I think that call is made [here](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/blob/f1c39fa611cb2b691e86c7818e4ee388a2eaa42b/spyder/widgets/variableexplorer/objecteditor.py#L88)

The problem is that both widgets look more or less the same, so one tend to think that receive the same result in both cases, but the **DataFrameEditor** allows mixed types and the **ArrayEditor** not.

You can try to inspect the array variables in the IPython console until the support is finally released in **Spyder** for the proper Widgets.

Comment: Note that my references were to the code stand in the moment you'd made the question. The question was updated reflecting another stack trace, but the problem might be the same.

Comment: But for the udemy course followers, the tutor actually has support for it. Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/49347986/4010017

Answer (score 5):

Use the following code:

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('Data.csv')
X = pd.DataFrame(dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 4):

This is because the array has more than one data-type so it can't show an object with more than one datatype because it can't select a single type.. But if it has only one datatype the type is 'float64' so it can be seen.

Answer (score 4):

As long as your variables type are not same and in variable explorer you see this as object, it means variable needs to be converted to same type in your case.
You can fix it by using fit_transform():

Here is related part of the code for in that tutorial:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder , OneHotEncoder
labelencoder_X_1 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 1] = labelencoder_X_1.fit_transform(X[:, 1])
labelencoder_X_2 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 2] = labelencoder_X_1.fit_transform(X[:, 2])
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [1])
X = onehotencoder.fit_transform(X).toarray()
```

Answer (score 3):

There are two things you can do to bypass the variable viewer in Spyder.  You can either

A) use "print (X)" to reveal the contents of X, or

B) Simple use the IPython console by simply typing X and hit return.  That too allow you to quickly reveal if the discussed ML functions are doing their job.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17776473)

Comment: The problem is better defined in the comments by the original poster.  The problem is the Spyder GUI.  Newbies in a Machine Language course with little Python experience are being asked to review ML functions using the GUI.  My post provides a way for those newbies to move forward and stay focused on the material as provided by the instructor.

Answer (score 3):

It is yet not supported by Spyder but you can use IPyhon Console to print those values by directly typing variable name to it.

Answer (score 2):

With the updated version of spyder you cannot see mixed arrays anymore using variable explorer. You can print the array instead in the console to inspect it.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, because I insisted on using the exact format for the `y` variable as for `x`, i.e. 
`x[: , 0] = labelencoder_x.fit_transform(x[:,0])`,
and I used
`y[:] = labelencoder_y.fit_transform(y[:]) *(taking into account the syntax for the fit transform for y)*`

The above made the dtype for `y_test` and `y_train` *"object"* which can't be viewed on Spyder in the variable explorer.

When I used the exact line used by the instructor:
`y = labelencoder_y.fit_transform(y)`.
The dtype changed to `int64` which can be viewed in the variable explorer.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me :

```
import pandas as pd
labels = pd.read_csv('labels/labels.csv')
# object arrays are currently not supported exception
breeds = labels.breed.unique()
# Supported Version 
# working fine
breeds = pd.DataFrame(labels.breed.unique())
```

Answer (score 1):

Add

X = pd.DataFrame(X)

to convert X object to dataframe which can be checked in spyder also without the error.

Worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

This is because the data are not encoded. All the categorical data should be "encoded".
After looking at the data in variable explorer of your sypder(https://i.stack.imgur.com/uApwt.jpg), it is clear that 
X contains data about some country (like [France, 44.0, 72000]), so the name of the country should be encoded and similarly
y contains "Yes" or "No", so it should also be encoded

Add the following code after line 21, you will be able to see the object array

```
# Encoding categorical data

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder

'''
To prevent the machine learning equations from thinking 
(if there are more than one country) that one country is greater than 
another, use the concept of dummy variables    
''' 
labelencoder_X = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 0] = labelencoder_X.fit_transform(X[:, 0])
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [0])
X = onehotencoder.fit_transform(X).toarray()

'''
Since y is dependent variable, the machine learning model will know 
that its a category, so we are going to use only the LableEncoder()
'''
labelencoder_y = LabelEncoder()
y = labelencoder_y.fit_transform(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Issue was the line

```
oneHotEncoder.fit_transform(X).toarray()
```

Which does not assign the data back to the X array. Instead, the following line should fix the issue:

```
X=oneHotEncoder.fit_transform(X).toarray()
```

Answer (score 0):

If data is of same type example int or float, it will show in variable explorer, otherwise it doesn't support if data has string and int for example.

But there is solution to check data, you can do it in IPython Console.

Answer (score 0):

I have actually worked through this course, and the instructor never opens the object in the variable viewer. I went back to check and he actually does try, and runs into the exact same issue as you. When viewing the dataset, he views it in the console, not in the variable viewer.

As mentioned above, you can convert the whole thing to a dataframe which you then can open in the variable viewer:

```
dataset = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(dataset)
```

You should now be able to view the data in the variable viewer, along with the categorical variables, as you like. 
At the time I only viewed the dataset myself in the console by entering the name of the imported data, but this is also still a working approach on the newest version of Spyder.