# Object array is not picklable

Tags: python, arrays, class, pickle, spyder

I made a class in python like the following:

```
class myClass():
    _fields_ = [1, 2]
```

where field_1 & field_2 are supposed to be integers.

Then I created an array that its elements are of the class `myClass` as following:

```
array = [ myClass() for i in range(5)]
```

When I wanted to check the values of the elements of `array` in the variable inspector, it gives my the following message:

```
"Spyder was unable to retrieve the value of this variable from the console." 
"The error message was: Object array is not picklable"
```

My question is: How can I check the values of the elements of the array?

Comment: Why do you have "graph" in the title and "array" in the question? These two words mean very different things.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spyder Python "object arrays are currently not supported"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41494358/spyder-python-object-arrays-are-currently-not-supported)

Comment: If you are using python 2 extending `class myClass(object)` might be sufficient. (SyntaxTip: class names start by an Upper-case letter).

Comment: @stovfl the Spyder version is 2.3.7

Comment: @ImanolLuengo I did the edits you suggested, but still couldn't check the array in the variable inspector.

Comment: @SergeBallesta You are right. It was mistyping and I edited the question.

Comment: @SergeBallesta: Have you a source/link for this statement: _**And a class object is indeed not pickable...**_

Answer (score 1):

Check out the following **Spyder** related sites:

> : [Downloads, bug reports and feature requests](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder)
>   : [Discussions](http://groups.google.com/group/spyderlib)

---

Verifyed, `pickle` can handle `object array` given in Question.
**The following works without failure**.

```
pick_array = pickle.dumps(array)
unpick_array = pickle.loads(pick_array)
```

***Tested with Python:3.4.2***

---

To verify your *Spyder* is able to show a `array` at all, check the following:

```
array = [ i for i in range(5)]
```

Try to show the variable `array` with Inspector.

If you are able to view the variable, it's a limitation from your Spyder Version **to handle  object array**.

Comment: Actually I already tried this solution and it worked. According to what you said it's a limitation in my Spyder to handle the object. Any suggestions to solve this issue?